# vtk python can't be detected

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

`VTK` was working fine until I updated it.  I made sure to turn on all the python linking etc.

Now, when I run `mayavi2`, I receive:

```
dustin@dustin:~$ mayavi2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/mayavi2", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mayavi==4.3.0', 'console_scripts', 'mayavi2')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2309, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2015, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mayavi/scripts/mayavi2.py", line 457, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: libvtkCommonPythonD.so.5.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
________________________________________________________________________________
Do you have vtk installed properly?
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the file `libvtkCommonPythonD.so.5.10` and added it to added to LD Library Path

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/vtk-5.10`